# How to validate QlineEdit in order to allow to write a string only or allow to write numbers only

Tags: c++, qt, validation, qt5

I have a `QLineEdit`.

I want when the user enters data in that field allows only to enter the numbers, or allows only to enter the text string, and so on.

I know the method to do that and that by using `void QLineEdit::setValidator (const QValidator * v)`, **but I don't know how to use this method?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
QRegExp rx("regex");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);

QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
edit->setValidator(validator);
```

Where regex for string:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

For numbers:

```
[0-9]+
```

Comment: @LionKing Please show your code, you should include QRegExp and QRegExpValidator and write QRegExp rx("[0-9]+"); if it does not help, then show your code

Comment: @LionKing it should be QRegExp pattern("[a-zA-Z]+"); compiler can't convert you code.

Comment: @LionKing There are `QIntValidator` and `QDoubleValidator` for numbers. It is big overhead to use regular expressions for numbers validating. Also, there may be internationalization problems.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Thanks, but can you please show me the ideal way to use the validation, as I requested previously.

Comment: @LionKing  QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(100, 999, this); and set it as in my answer, as you can see, with this class you can set range if you need this.

Comment: @LionKing next time, please, show some code with your attemps. Because phrases like "but I don't know how to use this method?" sounds like "write a code instead of me, because I'm lazy".

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Thank you, but believe me I'm not a lazy, because really I don't know anything about how to use `setValidator` method. Anyway, thank you for hint.

Comment: @LionKing did you try to read documentation, before asking such questions? There is an example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qintvalidator.html#details

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Before answer on this question I was don't understand the example which in your hyperlink, but now I understood, the subject was dependent on the answer on this question, and everything after that would be easy to understand. `(Thank you for vote down)`.